# Sharing articles on Social media loses the images after posting

Tags: 7, social-network, meta-tags

This seems to have only happened recently. Has anyone found a fix?
I'm using D7 with Metatag, Metatag:Facebook & Metatag:Opengraph.

However, I'm not convinced the issue is with any of these modules, and here is why:

When I share an article on facebook (other platforms are doing the same), the image shows correctly in the preview but when it is displayed on a user's profile, either no image or a "safe image" from the platform's CDN is displayed.

When shared on Facebook, the image is replaced with something from FB's CDN:

```
<img height="74" width="74" alt="BBC One releases first look at new thriller Vigil" class="datstx6m pmk7jnqg j9ispegn kr520xx4 k4urcfbm" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin" src="https://external-lcy1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQHbIThpTniFRwWa&amp;w=74&amp;h=74&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Frts.org.uk%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2FRTS_logo.png&amp;cfs=1&amp;ext=jpg&amp;ccb=3-5&amp;_nc_hash=AQHydfUnOTwoNOs0">
```

When shared on Linked in, the image is replaced with something from LI's CDN:

```
<img width="308" src="https://media-exp3.licdn.com/dms/image/sync/C4D27AQEfVR4ye-RMcA/articleshare-shrink_480/0/1622988826826?e=1623243600&amp;v=beta&amp;t=8PksYkc4Zp8EI-ENytwmeh4x-hjIQKT1MBLtq_1r2SU" loading="lazy" height="164" alt="" id="ember91" class="ivm-view-attr__img--centered pab-featured-item__image lazy-image ember-view">
```

[image: the preview image when I enter the URL]

[image: article being posted]

[image: The image has been replaced !]

Comment: Have you tried the facebook or twitter debugger? https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Also, what does the og:image meta tag show? `<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/wh_social-share-1100x740.png" />` Is there anything in your network that could be blocking/rewriting ULRs from social media accessing images? Because the images are shared outside of the network, I always try to prove full URLs to the social sharing image. Relative paths can be problematic.

Comment: I've tried both those debugging tools and the sample it displays shows the image.

Comment: `<meta property="og:image" content="https://rts.org.uk/sites/default/files/styles/9_column_landscape/public/p09gft73.jpeg?itok=VXhyYRK9">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that it was a combination of a missing OG:image tag due to the metatag module looking at the incorrect image field, but even after I'd fixed that - it's worth noting that Facebook (and other platforms) cache the sample images that are used - it appears that they cahe the image even if a different user has already shared it, so you may need to wait to see the new image